# Phone Stolen- I removed my google account from the device, any way to still remote wipe?

Tags: security

I should have tried to erase the phone before removing the account from the phone, but was too hasty.  I've changed all my passwords, but can the thief still see all my old emails and messages?

Is there any way I can still remote wipe this phone?

Comment: Assuming your phone is locked your data is secure